# Why will my JQuery only run if I place window load function within?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My following code will not function, unless I place it all

```
$(window).load(function(){
// within here
}
```

How can I get my code to run without requiring the above function?
Thanks!

My code:

```
// Player controls
    var timer = null;
    $('#left').mousedown(function() {
                moveLeft(); // Do it now
                timer = setInterval(moveLeft, 5); // Then every 100 ms
          }).mouseup(function() {
                clearInterval(timer); // And stop it
          });

    function moveLeft() {
          var nextpos = parseInt($('#player').css('left')) - 5;
          if (nextpos > 0) {
                $('#player').css('left', nextpos + 'px');
          }
    }
    $('#right').mousedown(function() {
                moveRight(); // Do it now
                timer = setInterval(moveRight, 5); // Then every 100 ms
          }).mouseup(function() {
                clearInterval(timer); // And stop it
          });

    function moveRight() {
          var nextpos = parseInt($('#player').css('left')) + 5;
          if (nextpos < PLAYGROUND_WIDTH - 100) {
                $("#player").css("left", ""+nextpos+"px");
          }
    }

// Timer
$(function(){
    var timercount = 30;
      countdown = setInterval(function(){
        $("#timer").html(timercount);
        if (timercount <= 0) {
          $("#timer").html("TIMES UP");
        }
        timercount--;
      }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: That wrapper is required because the page may not be fully loaded when your code is executed.  Why do you not want to use the load function?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're not trying to get a comparison of why you need $(window).load and not $.ready. Anyway, javascript is run as it's seen. You've got jquery looking up elements (#right, #player, etc) that probably haven't been loaded into the page yet. So, because these elements are not on the page, jQuery can't bind these events to them.

Read this through - it may more thoroughly answer your question. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Though, after re-reading the http://api.jquery.com/ready/ page, it also gives the difference between a .load and .ready, so really - go there and read :)

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code at the end of the page, rather than in the header, those elements should be loaded by the time the javascript runs.

That said, if your code is comparing the size of images, the images need to be loaded first...

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it below your HTML..

```
<body>
//your html stuff here that uses the script

<script type="text/javascript">
// the js code here
</script>

</body>
```